# regexec, presence or absence of brackets, behavior

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to understand why adding the brackets in the following example gets a different response.  Any explanations would be appreciated

```
> regexec("\\w*\\.*", "12.3")
[[1]]
[1] 1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 3

> regexec("[\\w*\\.*]", "12.3")
[[1]]
[1] 3
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `[` and `]`, the special characters like `.`, `*` etc are treated as normal characters and here you have given a regex with a character class enclosing `\\w*\\.*` which looks for a word character (letter, digit or underscore) or a `*` or a `.` (i.e. maximum one character is allowed).

A character class allows the occurrence of any of the characters specified inside it. Here, inside character class, `\\w` is treated as a `\w`. `\\.` is treated as a dot (no special meaning for `.` here)

Against `\\w*\\.*` a matching pattern contains zero or more word characters followed by zero or more `.` and your input is `12.3` which has two digits followed by a dot, causing a match length of 3.

Against `[\\w*\\.*]` a matching pattern contains any of the following occurring once and only once - word character, *, .

As your input has a digit at the beginning, it is matched. So match length is 1.

Answer (score 2):

Brackets create a "character class," which means "match one of any of the listed characters."  The first one is "Match 0 or more \w followed by 0 or more periods."  The second is "Match one of \w, asterisk, period, or asterisk (redundant)."